# Why do user pages not show up when searching through user pages?

Tags: support, user-search

Yesterday, when I went to https://stackoverflow.com/users and, in the text box marked "Type to find users", entered "bjarne", this gave me 5 users, none of which was the one I was looking for.

So [I used google](http://www.google.com/#q=bjarne+stroustrup+site:stackoverflow.com), which found me [the user page I was looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109934/bjarne-stroustrup) as the very first hit.

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Comment: Oops, how's that? You can answer questions without registering?? (Oh, and thanks for answering!)

Comment: @KennyTM - If this is the case then why can I search for *bjarne* and see [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/348335/bjarne)

Comment: @Barry: That's actually a bug; it allowed searching for unregistered users if you entered the *exact* name. That was never intended and will be fixed shortly. Then you won't see that user anymore :)

Comment: @balpha -ah I see. Well I see for now but soon I won't! :)

Comment: @sbi I think your link is "broken" :)

Comment: @balpha: FWIW, [I have asked a follow-up question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72285/why-cant-i-find-unregistered-users-in-user-search).