# Why can't I find unregistered users in user search?

Tags: discussion, user-search

This is a follow-up question to [Why do user pages not show up when searching through user pages?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72215/why-do-user-pages-not-show-up-when-searching-through-user-pages) where KennyTM pointed out that the user in question isn't registered and therefore can't be found.

This raises the question, why is a user who has answered questions, and has a user page, not findable through the user search?

Comment: @random: You do use a strange lorem ipsum.

Comment: I regret that I can't see more of @random's activity feed.

Comment: If this is the case then why can I search for *bjarne* and see [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/348335/bjarne) - I have asked the same question on the answer provided by KennyTM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, I think it should show up too.  It's especially weird since unregistered users *do* show up when you navigate through `/users` pages.  I can't see the point of not having them show up in search (it can be confusing; I remember getting confused once long ago).

If they are not supposed to show up in search, it's better to remove them from `/users` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but my [WAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_Wild-Ass_Guess) is that indexing and/or returning results for unregistered users was removed for performance reasons.  As an optimization it makes a good deal of sense because:

1. there are likely to be many more unregistered users than registered ones<sup>1</sup>, and
2. it seems unlikely that searching for unregistered users will turn up any useful results.

It seems possible that the [new search engine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/1438) will allow performant searches of unregistered users.  But will it be worth whatever extra cost that implies?  Without knowing the cost-side of the equation (we need a Stack Exchange developer to look into that), we can only consider the possible benefits: why would such a search be useful?

I can think of two use cases:

1. Find a post from an unregistered user whose name you happen to know.

   Perhaps the name was memorable or because you know it from some context outside the site.  For instance, I know that [Tommy Wasserman](http://www.orebromissionsskola.se/viewNavMenu.do?menuID=239), a foremost expert on the New Testament book of Jude, provided an an answer on Biblical Hermeneutics.  However, a [search of users](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/users) turns up nothing.
2. Find all the unregistered users with the same name.

   When you think about it, this is a sort of subset of the first case.  I've noticed a fellow on Biblical Hermeneutics who starts a new unregistered user to ask a question or two before taking an extended break.  He goes by Radz Brown or something.  Again, the name does not turn up in the user search or even a [full text search](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?q=radz) of the site.

### Google to the rescue

Thankfully, Google doesn't ignore unregistered users.  So I can find [Tommy Wasserman's post](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:hermeneutics.stackexchange.com%20%22Tommy%20Wasserman%22) (and any posts that reference his work) and all of [Radz' unregistered users](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:hermeneutics.stackexchange.com%20radz).  Unlike the built-in search, Google doesn't know that I'm just interested in user profiles, so we get all the various places each unregistered user shows up: badge lists, question lists, tagged questions, answer bodies, and etc.  But we can narrow the search down:

```
site:[site_name].stackexchange.com/users "User Name"
```

That gives us just the users who have that particular name.

Rather than expand the built-in search, perhaps it would make sense to link to the Google search when a search for an unregistered user comes up empty.

---

**Footnote:**

<sub>1. This conjecture is hard to prove without being able to search unregistered users.</sub>

Comment: Just a FYI: as a moderator on BH, you have access to a tool that'll search all accounts, reg and unreg, by name / email / credentials / worst fears / whatever. Useful for handling type-2 situations.