# User search missing results

Tags: support, users-page, user-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do user pages not show up when searching through user pages?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72215/why-do-user-pages-not-show-up-when-searching-through-user-pages)

The user page search is not returning all matching results. I don't think it happens for all search terms, but I can't be sure of that. Here's what I'm seeing:

On the user page for OnStartups, if I search for the name "Stacey", I only get back 1 result, which is for "Brice Stacey".

[image]

However, I know there are at least 3 user accounts matching the name "Stacey":

http://answers.onstartups.com/users/3167/stacey 
http://answers.onstartups.com/users/4706/stacey 
http://answers.onstartups.com/users/9534/stacey

*Can anybody explain what is happening here?*

(Apologies for posting this here, and not on the OnStartups Meta, but I figured it would get more attention here. Plus this is probably an SE wide issue.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unregistered accounts does not appear in search result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is this a new "feature"? In the old days these user accounts showed up in my search results. It makes it a bit hard for mods to keep the site organized when we can't easily find problem users.

Comment: @Zuly, I am not sure since when, but at least from 2010 according to this similar question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72285/why-cant-i-find-unregistered-users-in-user-search

Comment: According to @balpha what I was seeing before was a bug that allowed searching for unregistered users if you entered the exact name. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72215/why-do-user-pages-not-show-up-when-searching-through-user-pages It looks like it has been "fixed".

Comment: @Zuly, you're right, previously you can search unregistered user by exact name. but it was bug, so balpha fixed it - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72215/why-do-user-pages-not-show-up-when-searching-through-user-pages#comment-174602 - **Edit**: I was typing the same thing when you commented above.